# Appending input field to div

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am trying to append input fields to div after a button is clicked, everything works fine but if I writing in any field and add another field all values of the input fields are lost. The values are not persisting.

```
 const addLink = document.querySelector("#addLink")
    if(document.contains(addLink)){
      addLink.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
         node = node +1;
        var linknode =`
    <div class="col-md-6 pr-md-1 ${nodeClass}">
      <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend" data-targetClass="${nodeClass}">
            <div class="input-group-text close btn-danger  ${triger}" type="button">
              <i class="tim-icons icon-simple-remove "></i>
            </div>      
          </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control lName" placeholder="Instagram" data-target="${vmodal}">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 pl-md-1 ${nodeClass}">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control l-url-model" data-target="${vmodal}" type="text" placeholder="https://instagram.com" />
      </div>
    </div>`;
    
      
        linknodes.innerHTML += linknode
```

Comment: Does your addLink button happen to be inside of the form? Make sure it's got the `type=button` attribute.

Comment: It outside the form.